# AppleScript: Delimiters not working, and tab separated URLS

Tags: csv, applescript, html-parsing, delimiter

I'm trying to obtain a list of Financial Times URL's for today's newspaper. I've done this by getting the source code from FT.com, then by used delimiters to parse the html source code, and now I'm trying to save each url as comma-separated value file (.txt extension).

I've been able to get as far as parsing the html source code. But my problem lies with saving the urls as a csv file (or a list of urls, separated by paragraphs).

*here is my applescript:*

```
on run

set query_url to "http://www.ft.com/uk-edition"
set query_url_source to do shell script "/usr/bin/curl " & quoted form of query_url

set p to query_url_source
set ex to extractBetweenLong(p, "><a href=\"/cms/s", ".html")

return ex

end run

--delimiters subroutine:

to extractBetweenLong(SearchText, startText, endText)
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters -- save them for later.
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText -- find the first one.
set liste to text items of SearchText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText -- find the end one.
set extracts to {}
repeat with subText in liste
    if subText contains endText then
        copy text item 1 of subText to end of extracts
    end if
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid -- back to original values.
return extracts
end extractBetweenLong
```

My output is as follows:

{"^!DOCTYPE html ... subs5", "/0/0130d092-c473-11e1-9c1e-00144feabdc0", "/0/cb8a70a0-c469-11e1-a98c-00144feabdc0", ..., "/0/02eaa328-c468-11e1-9c1e-00144feabdc0",}

- My first question is why does the first string (^!DOCTYPE html...) exist? There must be something wrong with my delimiter subroutine, since my first 'startText' delimiter should not include the the "DOCTYPE ... subs5" (the subs5 HTML tab ends with .html), so that might be an indication that my subroutine star
- Second How can I save each URLs as a list, separated by commas or line-breaks? I first would like to put the string: "www.ft.com/cms/s" before each URL, but I believe I can figure that out myself.

Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppleScript's text item delimiters define the substrings to use when breaking up strings into a list of text items, and the substring that is used when reassembling a list of text items back into a string.

1. The text item delimiters just define where the string is broken up, not which pieces to keep or discard.  In your script, you can throw away the first text item in your extraction handler with something like:

   **set liste to rest of text items of SearchText**
2. Getting the text items results in a *list* of strings (the text items).
3. Just as you use text item delimiters to break the strings apart, you can use them when putting the pieces back together, for example setting the text item delimiters to a comma or line-break before coercing the list back to text.  The "www.ft.com/cms/s" part can also be put in there, although (like #1 above), you will also need to add it before the first item, for example:

```
set tempTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ("," & return & "www.ft.com/cms/s")
set ex to ex as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID
return "www.ft.com/cms/s" & ex
```

Comment: May I ask one question concerning how your answer to question three works:
I now understand how you've separated one number from another, and how you've combined the "www.ft.com". But I'm curious as to how your code does not require a loop to make these changes to the all of of the URLs? I'm not used to applescript and am struggling a bit to write my program.

Comment: AppleScript applies the text item delimiters (the delimiter text is placed in between each of the list items) when the list is coerced into a string.  The Cocoa equivalents for the text item delimiters would be something like NSString's componentsSeparatedByString: and componentsJoinedByString: methods.